# angular store and retrieve more inline data

Tags: angularjs

I was working on a simple angular functionality. but got stuck.

e.g.

```
<input type="radio" data-ng-model="package" value="1" data-more="some text here" />
```

Is there a way to retrieve the more data?

I know I can get the value by this using this: {{package}}

Cheers

Comment: Where are you wanting to retrieve it at? You could create a directive called 'more' then have that passed in on your scope using = or @

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I have 3 checkboxes all with model package just what to retrieve the id (the value) but also do some maths and just print it with that more data.

Comment: There is angular.element to get attribute data like jquery .. but i don't know why i can not get it work in plunker :S  /i use in my project thoughhttps://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element